# Restful application in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, web-services, swift, rest

I am new to Swift/iOS programming and I wanted to know how exactly you are supposed to handle web services with a restful method, what to use and what to take into account?

I'm already used to web services, and I can launch services using PHP servers for example, and also used to restful applications meanly in Java applications. I only need to know best framework to manipulate JSON or XML data using iOS Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really a matter of taste. Personally I prefer using the native libraries where I can. So let's start with the native options.

**1.** NSURLConnection

You can use it like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "resourceUrl")!
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) in
    if error == nil {
        let results: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
        if results != nil {
            //handle the response here
        }
    } else {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

**2.** NSURLSession

Introduced in iOS7, this is generally the better approach.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "resourceUrl")!
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let dataTask = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if (error == nil) {
            var error : NSError?
            let parsedObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,
                error:&error)

                //handle the response here
    }
}

dataTask.resume()
```

**3.** If you want to go with a more sophisticated approach meaning using an external library you can choose `Alamofire` which can be found [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). You can read about its pros vs the standard native approaches.

**4.** If you are exclusively dealing with JSON then you can go with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which makes parsing JSON really easy.

Good luck!